# Wordpress Custom Contact Forms Jquery tools tooltip undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I am using the Custom Contact Forms plugin in Wordpress. I didn't have any javascript errors from the plugin until I upgraded everything (wordpress and plugins). I am now having the following javascript errors. My question is regarding the second one but if you know how to fix the first, that would be great too!

1) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined jquery.tools.min.js?ver=3.9:1
(anonymous function) jquery.tools.min.js?ver=3.9:1
(anonymous function) jquery.tools.min.js?ver=3.9:1

2) Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function custom-contact-forms.js?ver=3.9:27
(anonymous function) custom-contact-forms.js?ver=3.9:27
j jquery-2.1.0.min.js?ver=2.1.0:2
k.fireWith jquery-2.1.0.min.js?ver=2.1.0:2
o.extend.ready jquery-2.1.0.min.js?ver=2.1.0:2
I jquery-2.1.0.min.js?ver=2.1.0:2

The tooltip function errors:

```
// Custom Contact Forms plugin javascript
var RecaptchaOptions = {
    theme : 'custom',
    custom_theme_widget: 'recaptcha_widget'
};

$j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function(){
    $j('<a></a>')
        .addClass('ccf-popover-close')
        .html('[close]')
        .prependTo('.ccf-popover');
    $j('.ccf-popover').css({'padding' : '10px 14px 10px 10px'});
    $j("a#in").click(function(){
        var sel = ".ccf-popover" + cid;
        $j(".ccf-popover1").fadeIn();

    });
    $j(".ccf-popover-close").click(function(){
        $j(".ccf-popover").hide();
    });
    $j('.show-field-instructions').click(function() {

    });

    $j(".ccf-tooltip-field").tooltip({
        position: "center right",
        offset: [-2, 10],
        effect: "fade",
        opacity: 0.7,
        tipClass: 'ccf-tooltip'

    });

    $j("#ccf-form-success").delay(500).fadeIn('slow');
    $j("#ccf-form-success .close").click(function() {
        $j("#ccf-form-success").fadeOut();                                            
    });

});
```

Files included in head:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://test.marrinc.org/wp-content/plugins/jquery-updater/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js?ver=2.1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://test.marrinc.org/wp-content/plugins/custom-contact-forms/js/custom-contact-forms-datepicker.js?ver=3.9'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://test.marrinc.org/wp-content/plugins/custom-contact-forms/js/custom-contact-forms.js?ver=3.9'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://test.marrinc.org/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
```

The only thing I can think of at this point is either jquery-migrate being included after or an error with the jquery tools file itself. I've attempted to find an updated library without the whole jquery library included but the CDN is down on the jquery tools site. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: are these files loading with the website correctly? I don't think this password thing is a good thing

Comment: Nope. I removed the password and I still get errors.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am getting the exact same javascript errors you were.

Comment: I am having the same issue.  Custom Contact Forms includes jquery.tools.min.js which references something that comes back with the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using jQuery 2.1. Try using jQuery 1.11.1. You might also want to load jquery-migrate before your contact forms plugin files.